# Groovy future.get() returns null

Tags: java, groovy, async-await, completable-future

I am working on a Groovy project to merge Sheets, but faced an issue over my async utils. I narrowed it down to that.

Here is the `AsyncUtils`:

```
package com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript.utils

import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.Future

public final class AsyncUtils {
    private static ExecutorService threadPool;
    
    public static <T> Future<T> StartAsyncTask(Closure<T> onTask) { 
        return this.GetThreadPool()
            .submit(onTask);
    }
    
    public static <T> T AwaitResult(Future<T> future) {  
        return future.get();
    }
    
    public static ExecutorService GetThreadPool() { 
        if (!this.threadPool)
            this.threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        
        return this.threadPool;
    }
}
```

To try to resolve it, I write JUnit test case simulating my use case in the real project codebase:

```
package com.signaturemd.sposZohoMergeScript.utils;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class AsyncUtilsTest {

    @Test
    void testAwaitResult() {
        final List promises = [
            {
                Thread.sleep(100);
                return "hello";
            },
            {
                Thread.sleep(50);
                return "world";
            },
        ].collect { Closure onTask -> return AsyncUtils.StartAsyncTask(onTask) }
        
        promises.each { promise -> 
            final String result = AsyncUtils.AwaitResult(promise);
            
            assert result != null;
        }
    }

}
```

The assertion is failing, as `result` is somehow `null` after awaiting the result...

What is causing this to happen, and does this mean I should wait on all promises (Futures) to resolve before starting unit of work (in my case merging)?

DISCLAIMER: I'm on Java 17

Comment: It's not even working when I do wait for them all to resolve...

Comment: Do you have the same problem when you write the same logic with plain Java? The type `Closure<T>` implements `Callable<T>` *and* `Runnable`, so which `submit` method has been invoked? • But what’s the purpose of this `AsyncUtils` class anyway? Why create extra code, just to be able to write `AsyncUtils.AwaitResult(promise)` instead of `promise.get()`? • The lazy initialization in `GetThreadPool()` is not thread safe and obsolete anyway; just declaring `private static final ExecutorService threadPool  = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();` would be lazily initialized *and* thread safe.

Comment: It should be obvious... The point of `AsyncUtils` is to abstract out the details related to asynchronous programming. Namely, I want my asynchronous programming in Groovy, to work like asynchronous programming work in JavaScript. Also, switching to Java is not an option for me. The rest of my codebase is in Groovy

Comment: There is nothing obvious here. First, calling a static method is not an abstraction. Second, making programming language X to work like programming language Y is not a useful goal. In the end, your own answer acknowledges that using Groovy’s built-in facilities makes more sense than trying to make it work like JavaScript. And I did never suggest to switch to Java. I only asked whether a Java equivalent exhibits the same behavior, which is a straight-forward method to find out, whether the problem is Groovy related or not.

Answer (score 1):

groovy [Closure](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Closure.html) implements both - Runnable and Callable.

```
def c={'world'}

println c.call()  // ==> prints world
println c.run()   // ==> prints null
```

when you are calling `ExecutorService.submit(Closure)` compiler chooses Runnable interface of the closure.

Casting `Closure` to `Callable` solves the issue

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import java.util.concurrent.Future
import java.util.concurrent.Callable

@groovy.transform.CompileStatic
public final class AsyncUtils {
    private static ExecutorService threadPool;
    
    public static <T> Future<T> StartAsyncTask(Closure<T> onTask) { 
        return this.GetThreadPool()
            .submit((Callable)onTask);  // <<== the only effective change
    }
    
    public static <T> T AwaitResult(Future<T> future) {  
        return future.get();
    }
    
    public static ExecutorService GetThreadPool() { 
        if (!this.threadPool)
            this.threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        
        return this.threadPool;
    }
}

def future = AsyncUtils.StartAsyncTask{
     Thread.sleep(1000)
     return "world"
}

assert AsyncUtils.AwaitResult(future)=='world'
```

Comment: I like it. I was able to get this problem solved parallel to this ( I discovered the `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync` and `CompletableFuture.thenApplyAsync` methods ), but this one is definitely getting the thumbs up

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I didn't need to create new thread pool or the equivalent of JS's `async`/`await` keywords. Just treat these `Future`s as the thennables...

- I don't need thread pool explicitly
- I don't need the `async`/`await` equivalent. It wouldn't work efficiently anyways. We want the first thennable that resolves, not to resolve them all in the order they're supplied.

I just change my util class to :

```
public final class AsyncUtils {
    
    public static <T> Future<T> StartAsyncTask(Closure<T> onTask) { 
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(onTask)
    }
}
```

and then my test case, understanding (and simulating) the problem a bit more, to:

```
@Test
    void testStartAsyncTask() { 
        final List<CompletableFuture> promises = [
           {
               Thread.sleep(100);
               return "hello";
           },
           {
               Thread.sleep(50);
               return "world";
           },
       ].collect { Closure onTask -> return AsyncUtils.StartAsyncTask(onTask) }

       promises.eachWithIndex { promise, int idx -> 
           promise.thenApplyAsync { String str ->
               if (idx == 0) { 
                   assert str.equals('world')
                   return
               }
               assert str.equals('hello')
           }
       }
    }
```

and all is well!